# Solutions of this set of linear congruences using Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Suppose m1, m2, ..., mk are positive integers > 1, not necessarily pairwise relatively
prime. Also Suppose a1, a2, ..., ak ∈ Z. What can be said about the solutions of the following set
of linear congruence equations?
x ≡ a1 (mod m1), x ≡ a2 (mod m2), x ≡ a3 (mod m3), ..., x ≡ ak (mod mk).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please don't duplicate (your?) prior questions.